# iOS Mobile SDK & CocoaPods Compiler Error

Tags: mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk

I've followed the instructions for adding the Salesforce Mobile SDK for iOS via CocoaPods (v. 0.36), but getting a compiler error, per the attached screenshots. Deployment target is iOS 8.1.

What am I missing?

[image: Compiler error]